# (AEM) Error: Can neither derive user name nor principal names when uploading asset

Tags: java, aem

I am trying to upload an asset to the Asset folder in Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) 6.5 as the admin user. However, I keep encountering the following error in the error log: "Can neither derive user name nor principal names for bundle com.day.cq.cq-tagging [458] and sub service tag-validation)" This error is preventing me from successfully uploading the asset.

I have already tried restarting AEM and clearing the browser cache, but the error persists.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is this a local server or a production server? What is the AEM version? Does it happen in another environments?